How to check if a directed graph (using adjacency list, not a adjacency matrix) is connected?
I have been looking for this algorithm in vain for a while. Thanks for your help

In the absence of finding anything, what have you tried? Even posting a rough outline in pseudo-code  is much more likely to get help.

A Google search for "directed graph adjacency list connected" was fruitful.

Jim, i dont want to check if my directed graph is strongly connected, just connected.

Why would the algorithm be different for an adjacency list?

@tothemoon Seems like if you understand how to do a connected check with an adjacency matrix, you can do it with an adjacency list. What exactly are you getting stuck on?
